# Saving different types of files through a service in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have successfully created a service and a listener to automatically save files in my Post Entity.

Everything works OK except I need to add another field to the Post entity:  'photo'. What is the right way to accomplish that using as much of the following code as possible? I tried to pass some parameters to the listener but I could get it working...

Brochures should be saved under: **web/uploads/brochures** and photos under: **web/uploads/photos**.

User has to provide both the brochure and a photo.

Thank you for all the help.

**services.yml:**

```
# brochure uploader service
app.brochure_uploader:
    class: AppBundle\Utils\FileUploader
    arguments: [ '%brochures_directory%' ]

# uploaded files for Post entity
app.doctrine_brochure_listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\BrochureUploadListener
    arguments: [ '@app.brochure_uploader' ]
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate }
```

**Utils/FileUploader.php:**

```
namespace AppBundle\Utils;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

class FileUploader
{
    private $targetDir;

    public function __construct($targetDir)
    {
        $this->targetDir = $targetDir;
    }

    public function upload(UploadedFile $file = null)
    {
        $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();
        $file->move($this->targetDir, $fileName);

        return $fileName;
    }

    public function getTargetDir() {
        return $this->targetDir;
    }
}
```

**EventLister/BrochureUploadListener.php:**

class BrochureUploadListener
{
    private $uploader;

```
public function __construct(FileUploader $uploader)
{
    $this->uploader = $uploader;
}

public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();
    $this->uploadFile($entity);
}

public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();
    $this->uploadFile($entity);
}

private function uploadFile($entity)
{
    if (!$entity instanceof Post) {
        return;
    }

    $file = $entity->getBrochure();

    if (!$file instanceof UploadedFile) {
        return;
    }

    $fileName = $this->uploader->upload($file);
    $entity->setBrochure($fileName);
}
```

}

**Form/PostType.php:**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
       [...]
        ->add('brochure', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType', array(
            'label' => 'Brochure (PDF file)',
            'data_class' => null,
        ))
       [...]
    ;
}
```

**Entity/Post.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 *
 * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "application/pdf" })
 */
private $brochure;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel.
Use VichUploaderBundle (also suggested by official Symfony documentation) and live happy

Comment: Thank you for the input, I am going to try this Bundle. I also want to get to know Symfony a little better, that's the reason for this question :)